# Как добавить дополнительное поле в стандартную модель пользователя Django?

Tags: django

Django 1.8.
Необходимо добавить дополнительное поле к аккаунту пользователя. Я пытаюсь сделать по двум разным примерам http://dunmaksim.blogspot.ru/2015/05/django-18.html и http://www.ruspython.com/blog/izuchaem-django-i-angularjs-1-rasshiryaem-vstroennuyu-model-user/ Но получается какая-то ерунда: есть стандартные таблицы auth_... и появляются для кастомной модели, но списки пользователей в них разные. Как сделать так, чтобы везде (при авторизации в админке, при отображении в админке списка пользователей, при создании createsuperuser и т.д.) использовались одни и те же пользователи?

Update:
Пробую сделать через создание своей модели UserProfile с полями пользователя User и дополнительным полем. На основе этой инструкции (часть 1) http://www.odmin4eg.ru/tag/django-registration/
Сделал по примеру, но в админке ничего не изменилось. Таблица в бд создалась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1, старый (раньше была проблема с изменением стандартного юзера): создать свою модель MyUser, у которой добавить поле типа OneToOneField к стандартному юзеру (лежит в settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL). Учтите, что это разные модели, просто связанные между собой. И придется следить за целостностью данных (то, что к MyUser привязан User - это факт, а то, что к User -> MyUser - уже нет).

Вариант 2: создать свою модель, наследовав от AbstractBaseUser (как раз первые 2 ссылки из Вашего вопроса). Не забудьте ее прописать в settings (AUTH_USER_MODEL, а также добавить в установленные приложения).
[Официальная документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) (в [русской](http://djbook.ru/rel1.8/topics/auth/customizing.html#specifying-a-custom-user-model) документации фрагмент не переведен) предупреждает, что это делать надо до первого вызова команды "migrate" и создания миграций. Иначе придется править все вручную. Если проект новый, можно просто удалить базу и заново создать - возможно, именно в этом Ваша проблема.